# Android Espresso test with @Parameters needs context

Tags: java, android, junit, android-espresso

Some context:

I'm writing a unit test that needs the Android context to load custom fonts from assets/, so have to use an Espresso test. (right?)

I want to use the `@Parameters` construction to generate tests with my provided inputs and expected outputs. The thing is that I need the Android context in the `@Parameters`-annotated method.

The problem:

The `@Parameters`-annotated method gets called first, even before the `@BeforeClass` and `@ClassRule`.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue, so wanted to share the solution in case someone else encounters the same.

What I basically do is delaying the initialisation of the Typefaces until the context is available:
In the `@Parameters` method I pass the names (Strings) of the Typefaces, and in the `@Test` method -when the Context is available- I create them.

My next timing issue was that a mock I needed at the same time was not yet initialised, because the `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks()` is called in my `@Setup` method which is called after the `@Parameters` method. But I simply omitted the `@Mock` and used the oldskool `Mockito.mock(Paint.class)` in my test method.